# Postgres is not making use of the available index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table like below:

```
create table Configuration(
      config_id varchar,
      configurations jsonb
)
```

And sample configurations columns looks like this:

```
{
   "orderProcessing":{
      "limit":3000,
      "config1":false,
      "config2":true,
      "config3": "Example Text"

   }
}
```

**Note**: 'orderProcessing' and 'limit' are not mandatory fields for configurations and will be missing in some rows.

I created a Btree index like this:

```
create index id_limit_idx on configuration(config_id, (configurations->'orderProcessing'->>'limit'));
```

I need to aggregate based on **orderProcessing.limit** like this:

```
select  configurations->'orderProcessing'->>'limit', count(*)
from configuration
where config_id = 'some_id'
GROUP BY (configurations->'orderProcessing'->>'limit')
```

But the query is not making use of the **id_limit_idx index** and instead does a Sequential scan.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=143843.65..143857.83 rows=22 width=40) (actual time=100.556..102.656 rows=6 loops=1)
   Group Key: (((configurations -> 'orderProcessing'::text) ->> 'limit'::text))
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=143843.65..143856.95 rows=110 width=40) (actual time=100.545..102.639 rows=27 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 5
         Workers Launched: 5
         ->  Sort  (cost=142843.57..142843.62 rows=22 width=40) (actual time=96.222..96.224 rows=4 loops=6)
               Sort Key: (((configurations -> 'orderProcessing'::text) ->> 'limit'::text))
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Worker 3:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               Worker 4:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=142842.75..142843.08 rows=22 width=40) (actual time=96.185..96.187 rows=4 loops=6)
                     Group Key: ((configurations -> 'orderProcessing'::text) ->> 'limit'::text)
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on configuration  (cost=0.00..142544.62 rows=59626 width=32) (actual time=5.988..86.741 rows=48976 loops=6)
                           Filter: (config_id = 'some_id'::text)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 279276
 Planning Time: 0.103 ms
 Execution Time: 102.699 ms
(20 rows)
```

This makes me suspect that the index I created is not correct. Maybe what I did is not the right way to create the index on nested field of a json element.

Really appreciate any help here.

Comment: "*the query is not making use of the id_limit_idx index*" - it clearly does as can see in the step `Bitmap Index Scan on id_limit_idx` - I don't see any Seq Scan in the plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The query plan that I provided is after I forced it to use index by setting `SET enable_seqscan = OFF`. That's why there is no Seq scan. But as you can see it's still doing `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan`. So, the question is why this step needed since the required information is already part of the index

Comment: Showing the one that uses the Seq Scan would be better to understand, why that happens.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I couldn't paste it in the comment. So, updated the query plan in the original question. Please take a look.

Comment: @user14870583 good. Never create comment for requested information. **Always** update the actual question. You can then just make a comment indication that it is done if you feel it is necessary to inform the requestor.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL cannot perform an index-only scan on an expression index like you created. That is not a matter of principle, it just hasn't been implemented yet.

An index-only scan could only use an index on `(config_id, configurations)`, but for understandable reasons that is not an option.

The best solution is to model `configurations->'orderProcessing'->>'limit'` as a normal table column rather than as a JSON attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my idea is to provide required information(in this case config_id and limit) as part of the same index. So, that postgress can just make use of the index without having to do table lookup(sequential or heap scan).

To experiment, I added new column and populated it
```
update configuration set limit = (configurations->'orderProcessing'->>'limit')::int
```
And created the index on 
```
create index id_limit on configuration(config_id, limit)
```
Then my query uses the index as expected.

That's why I am suspecting that original index is not correct